# Changing a objects attribute after a certain period of time? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that allows users to sign up. However, some users don't fully complete the sign up process, which relegates them to the status of inactive. After 30 days, if said user is still inactive, I'd like for their status to change to dormant. I'm new to this so if you need anymore information please ask. Thanks!

Comment: You could try the [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jmm pointed out, you can use the Whenever gem (https://github.com/javan/whenever) and set up a daily job:

```
# config/schedule.rb
every 1.day, at: '4:00 AM' do
  dormant_users = User.where(status: 'inactive').where('created_at < ?', 30.days.ago)
  dormant_users.update_all(status: 'dormant')
end
```

This code is an example, you might not handle the status of User the way I suggested.

Comment: how can I test if this works, I've edited and changed it to a `1.minute` and that it `puts "something"` but I don't see anything in the terminal.

Comment: You can test the execution by creating a simple txt file and add text in it, or simply create a txt file with timestamp as a name @Johhan

Comment: what I did was added this to the `schedule.rb` file `set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"`